# Get User Email id on clicking FaceBook 'Like' button?

Tags: facebook

I want the email address of the user when he/she clicks on the facebook Like button.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // like clicked
});
```

But the response only has the HREF.

How do I do this?

Comment: This is not possible due to security-restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

Simply you **can't**!

Even if the user is going to allow/authorize your application and you were asking for their emails (`email` permission), users may choose **not** to share it with you and provide you a *proxied* Facebook email address instead!