# When User clicks like button

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get User Email id on clicking FaceBook 'Like' button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249204/get-user-email-id-on-clicking-facebook-like-button)
>   [How can I send a facebook user an email when they click on the FB like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272802/how-can-i-send-a-facebook-user-an-email-when-they-click-on-the-fb-like-button)

When User clicks like button for a fan page on my facebook page how Can i retrieve some basic profile information (like firstname), email , id etc.. after user clicks like button?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: No, you cannot get that information programmatically just solely from a like click.

Comment: Yes, yes we are!  Otherwise it'd be a huge privacy issue outcry and facebook would once again cower to it and close that hole.